# beautifulsoup with get_text - handle spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I using BS4 (python3) for extracting text from html file. My file looks like this:

```
<BODY>
<P>Hello         World!</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When i calling `get_text()` method, the output is `Hello         World!`. Because it's HTML, I was expected to get `Hello World!` (two or more spaces are replaced with one space in HTML).

This Also relevant for this situation:

```
<BODY>
<P>Hello    
 World!</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I was expected to find "Hello World!" but it was "Hello    \n     World!".

How I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is to render the HTML and get the resulting text output. There must be a function somewhere (maybe not in BS) that performs this type of transformation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, neither `get_text(strip=True)` nor joining the `.stripped_strings` would work here because there is a single `NavigableString` in the `p` element in the second case and it's value is `Hello\n World!`. The newline is inside the text node in other words.

In this case, you will have to *replace the newlines* manually:

```
soup.p.get_text().replace("\n", "")
```

---

Or, to also handle the `br` elements (replacing them with newlines), you can make a converting function that will prepare the text for you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

data = """
<BODY>

<P>Hello
 World!</P>

<P>Hello
<BR/>
 World!</P>

</BODY>
</HTML>
"""

def replace_with_newlines(element):
    text = ''
    for elem in element.children:
        if isinstance(elem, NavigableString):
            text += elem.replace("\n", "").strip()
        elif elem.name == 'br':
            text += '\n'
    return text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for p in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(replace_with_newlines(p))
```

Prints (no newlines in the first case, a single newline in the second):

```
Hello World!
Hello
World!
```

Comment: Nice try, but this solution is limited. What about case that "<BR />" tag is in the HTML? In this case "\n" should be printed... HTML contains a lot of rules which I want to support.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever good points, I understand. Added some more information. In any case, looking for workarounds. Thanks.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever okay, please see the update and please test it on your actual use case. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

after got:

- `Hello         World!`
- `Hello \n World!`

then your should use `re` to do this kind of work:

```py
re.sub("\s+", " ", htmlPValue)
```

can got you expected:

- `Hello World!`
- `Hello World!`